# How to fix 'Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).'

Tags: javascript, html, web

[image: 1]

Every time when i'm trying to look for a code scripts it types [object Object], and so on.

[image: 2]
Here is what the console types.
I tried to look for solvings but i could not find anything.
Then i tried to turn off all extensions that i had (bcs it typed something abt extensions), but issue still remains.

Btw i tried to ask chatGPT abt this prob and then it said, it will explain issue properly.

It can mean a variety of things, but it typically indicates that some part of a web page's HTML or JavaScript code has not been properly formatted. In many cases, the browser will be able to render the webpage anyway, but the object that it does not recognize will cause the [object Object] error.

I was trying to install Neovim through scoop. Idk how this even happend.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but with ChatGPT's login. I've cleared caches, disabled plugins. FF dev edition, not-up-to-date. The problem could be with FireFox's security settings, like disabling fingerprinting. That would presumably block some inline page scripts.